# How to disable filename in ktlint?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, editorconfig

How and where i can to disable filename in ktlint?

I don t want to rename this class, but get next error:

> interface MainActivityContract should be declared in a file named MainActivityContract.kt (cannot be auto-corrected)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just added at the top of the file:

```
// ktlint-disable filename
```

**Note:** This works for `ktlint` version `0.24.0` and above.

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid that? I've added this in the .editorconfig disabled_rules=filename and it didn't work neither

Comment: Unfortunately, their documentation for globally disabling a rule using .editorconfig is currently broken: https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/issues/1592

Comment: Does not work after 0.50.0.  See separate answer for current suppression directive

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update for those using `ktlint` version `0.49.0` (or newer).

The `ktlint_disabled_rules` are no longer supported as it's stated [in the changelog](https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/releases/tag/0.49.0):

> Note that properties `disabled_rules` and `ktlint_disabled_rules` have been removed in this release.

That being said, the correct approach is now to use the [filename-associated](https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/0.49.0/rules/standard/#file-name) standard rule.

Add to the `.editorconfig`:

```
ktlint_standard_filename = disabled
```

Comment: The original question did explicitly ask for disabling the rule, But looking at the actual problem description, it would probably be better to suppress it for just the file in question.

Answer (score 1):

From 0.50.0 and on:

```
@file:Suppress("ktlint:standard:filename")

package foo
```

Docs:

https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/1.1.1/rules/standard/#ktlint-suppression-rule

https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/1.1.1/faq/#how-do-i-suppress-errors-for-a-lineblockfile

Answer (score 0):

Create in main folder file `.editorconfig`.
Add

```
ktlint_disabled_rules=filename
```

Full file for example:

```
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.{kt,kts}]
indent_size = 4
ktlint_disabled_rules=filename

[*.{yml,yaml}]
indent_size = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ktlint gradle then you can exclude using filename.

```
ktlint {
filter {
    exclude("**/generated/**")
    exclude("DateSanitizer.kt") // Replace your file name here
    include("**/kotlin/**")
}}
```

works with

```
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "11.6.0" apply false
```